# Qiskit: simulate a circuit using a backend noise model

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, noise

```
from qiskit import *


def random_bitstring_generator(bit_number, backend):
   

    bitstring = ""

    one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)
    one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit.h(0)
    one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit.measure(0, 0)

    for _ in range(bit_number):
        counts = execute(one_qubit_random_bit_generator_circuit, backend, shots=8192).result().get_counts()
        bit = list(counts.keys())[0]  
        bitstring += bit

    return bitstring


backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')

print(random_bitstring_generator(1024, backend))
```

1. How can i insert a noise model replicating IBM melbourne quantum machine for the circuit execution on simulator
2. Is there a way to be able export the sequence received as output to an text/csv file

Answer (score 1):

1. Add this code to your current code.
   This creates a simulator `backend` with the noise model from `ibmq_16_melbourne`.

```
from qiskit.providers.aer import QasmSimulator

provider = IBMQ.load_account()
ibmq_melbourne = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
backend = QasmSimulator.from_backend(ibmq_melbourne)

print(random_bitstring_generator(1024, backend))
```

2. Your output is already a string. If you want to dump that in a file, you can do this (this is a [general Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5214587/8146172), not related to Qiskit:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(random_bitstring_generator(1024, backend))
```

---

Note:
If you are trying generate a random number generator, probably you should have a look to [`qiskit.providers.ibmq.random`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/ibmq_random.html#module-qiskit.providers.ibmq.random).

Answer (score 0):

1. https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/2_device_noise_simulation.html
2. `bitstring` is a string, you can manipulate it and save it using Python commands.